# Why importing components from other files caused "Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid" error?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx, stack-navigator

I'm fairly advanced in iOS Swift language, but very new in react native framework or javascript language. I also have tried to find the right tutorial for stack navigator for hours but I can't find it. I'm currently using [this tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) to learn the basic of react native stack navigation, and would like to split the two screens into their own files. Basically, I want to mimic Swift with its `AppDelegate.swift` and View Controller's files. But it generates error like this:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the
>   file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.

That was old error. The new error now:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')
>
> This error is located at:
>
> in HomeScreen (at renderApplication.js:33)
>
> ...

Here's my current code. This has been edited according to the solutions.

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './ProfileScreen';

export default HomeScreen;

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent("TestProject", () => App);
```

HomeScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Button
        title="Go to Jane's profile"
        onPress={() =>
          navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

ProfileScreen.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

export default class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Jane Profile',
  };
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <Text>Welcome to Jane profile!</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any point out to any error and mistake in my code, as for now I'm completely oblivious to any problems in my code, as I'm learning this by myself. Please help. The first baby steps are always the hardest part every time I learn new language.

In this case, I'm trying to create a home screen with a button that leads to a second screen (profile) with a text in it. I'm also aware that I should be able to extract the name of the profile in the `ProfileScreen` which the `HomeScreen` sent, but I hardcoded it right now to make things simple for me to understand the solution.

Comment: You don't need `AppRegistry.registerComponent ("TestProject", () => Screen);` in each of your components. You need to register your top level component. Also, there's a space between the brackets and `registerComponent`, that should be removed. Try removing it from your screen files and add it to `App` - `AppRegistry.registerComponent("TestProject", () => App);`

Comment: @Dan "You need to register your top level component" --> in this case, do you mean I need to add `export default HomeScreen;` in the App.js?

Comment: Sorry just updated, remove your `AppRegistry` statements and put it inside the `App` component file. Your exports look fine to me.

Comment: Your navigation script is wrong!

Comment: You may also need to use `createStackNavigator` - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Comment: Hi @Dan, I have updated the code from your direction. Now I'm trying to do the `createStackNavigator`. But isn't that means that what is registered is the variable created from `createStackNavigator` (ex: `let stacks = createStackNavigator(...)`), and not the `App` above?

Comment: @RaajNadar can you please point me which one is wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: @ChenLiYong posted  an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './ProfileScreen';

const App = StackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreen },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
  headerMode: 'none'
});

export default () => <App />;
```

1. The name of the route should be same not mandatory but
   recommended.
2. Export the navigation element.
3. I don't even have a **AppRegistry** script in my project but it is still working.

If any issue comment that down below! Hope this will fix the issue

**Note :** This will work in **react-navigation version 1.5.11**

For **react-navigation v2** try this code

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './ProfileScreen';

const App = createStackNavigator({
   HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
   ProfileScreen: { screen: ProfileScreen },
}, {
   initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
   headerMode: 'none'
});

export default () => <App />;
```

Make the navigation script file global to access its props!

Comment: Yes I think this helps me understand more that `AppRegistry` sometimes can be left out, though I don't understand what's the significancy of `AppRegistry` now. Currently, the error now changes into a more direct StackNavigator error. It's like the system can't find `this.props.navigation.navigate` function in `HomeScreen`.

Comment: My react-navigation version is 2.0.1.

Comment: The StackNavigator should be accessible by all the routes! Don't import it in every page!

Comment: The error now "Can't find variable: createStackNavigator". I have tried to change the "c" to "C" but it still don't work.

Comment: My bad forgot to import that in line 2!

Comment: Oh okay, I have added the import. And after changes the `initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',` to `initialRouteName: 'Home'`, now it works!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: The issue was with the version! Always check the version in the docs and in you package.json file! Glad that it worked

Comment: Btw, can I ask why I don't need to use `AppRegistry.registerComponent` in this case? And can I actually never even have to ever use `AppRegistry.registerComponent` at all?

Comment: Maybe the AppRegistry is useful when you develope with android studio or xcode but in expo we don't need this. In my app I never used this still the app works fine!

Comment: After doing a small research I found that `This API only works in projects made with react-native init or in those made with Create React Native App which have since ejected.` I use create-react-native-app cli and I never ejected so AppRegistery API is not useful for me

Answer (score 1):

In react-native we don't register every component using `AppRegistry.registerComponent`, rather we register the parent component and parent component render child component. The changes that you need is to register the `App` component and export the `HomeScreen` and `ProfileScreen`.

**Sample**

**App.js**

```
...
const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('projectName', () => App)
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
...
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  ...
}
export default HomeScreen;
```

**ProfileScreen.js**

```
...
class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  ...
}
export default ProfileScreen;
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Oh I see. I thought the AppRegistry was the way to make the class known and can be used all over the project. Now I have updated the files, the issues about the import export files are gone, and I get another error. Now it relates directly to the stack navigator, I think.

Comment: Good to know that your `import` issue has been resolved :).