# Can I actually does not have to use AppRegistry.registerComponent in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Yesterday I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346719/why-importing-components-from-other-files-caused-invariant-violation-element-t) about React Native, and one of the answerer posted an answer without `AppRegistry.registerComponent`, but only using `export default <identifier>`.

I read from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html) that AppRegistry.registerComponent is very important because it provides "entry point" for the application. But why this simple `export default <identifier>` works? Does this means that I actually don't have to use `AppRegistry.registerComponent` whatsoever to make it work? What advantage / disadvantage does `AppRegistery.registerComponent` have over `export default` in defining an entry point in app?